# git starting an existing branch in a different remote

Tags: git

Someone has created a branch called aBranch, in a remote called theirRemote.
I want to pull down aBranch, but have it track to myRemote, so that when I push it will go to myRemote by default and not theirRemote.

I think I can co aBranch and deliberately push it to myRemote, but it will always default to theirRemote if I forget to specify. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to create a local branch called `aBranch` first (if you haven't already got one):

```
git checkout -b aBranch theirRemote/aBranch
```

Then use the `--set-upstream` option of `git push`:

```
git push --set-upstream myRemote aBranch
```

> `--set-upstream`
>
> For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less `git-pull` and other commands. For more information, see branch..merge in `git-config`.

Comment: You will want to create a local branch called `aBranch` first. Use `git checkout -b aBranch theirRemote/aBranch` to do that.

Comment: Thanks Greg, together those two suggestions worked, though I do not understand how I will ever learn. eg.: this is just something I must do by rote:
git checkout -b aBranch theirRemote/aBranch

Comment: @DaveC426913: It's worthwhile taking the time to learn what the parts of that command are: `git checkout` - command to switch branches; `-b` - create new local branch; `aBranch` - name of new local branch; `theirRemote/aBranch` - start point of new branch.

Comment: I find no pattern to able to be learn. Sometimes it's a prefix (myRemote other stuff), sometimes it's slash (myRemote/aBranch), sometimes it's a space (myRemote aBranch), sometimes it's simply implicit and not listed.

Comment: @DaveC426913: Agreed. I've been using git for years and I often have to look it up for some less-used commands. At least the documentation is complete and accurate.

Comment: I've edited your answer (didn't know I could do that!) to include both steps.

Comment: @DaveC426913: git's command set is kind of a mess, but there is actually a pattern, it's just violated at times.  In this case the fault (as it were) is in the `--set-upstream` option, and git grew a new `--set-upstream-to` option to fix it (to go back to pattern, as it were).  For details on what the pattern is *supposed* to be (despite routine violations) see `gitrevisions`: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html